# Error while Calculating Weighted Standard deviation in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

i am trying to calculate weighted standard deviation in R using the following code

```
library(dplyr)
library(matrixStats)
Output3 = Output2 %>%
  group_by(ProductionBatchNo) %>%
  summarize(
 across(as.numeric(`SDActVisc`)), 
 WtdSD = round(weightedSd(x=SDActVisc,w=Counts),2), 
 OverallCounts = n()
  )
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X, ...) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

I am not able to understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to now for sure without any data but this should work:

```
Output2 %>%
  group_by(ProductionBatchNo) %>%
  summarize(
    WtdSD = round(weightedSd(x = as.numeric(SDActVisc), w = Counts), 2), 
    OverallCounts = n(), .groups = "drop"
    )
```

What are you trying to do with the `across` function? You are not using it correctly anyways.

Comment: i was trying to perform it first on one variable and then repeat the same on 40 other variables in the dataset, so had made use of the across function